# ')' expected error when formatting a string

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I am currently stuck on a piece of work I am creating. In Visual Studio, I have a gridview which is bound to a datasource from a SQL table. I have a bit type column named Sold and what I am trying to do is use a drop down box (which is bound to the same source) and according to that selected index, change the sold row for that ID to 1 - to show that its been sold oddly enough!

Here is my code for the procedure to update my database.

```
Sub markAsSold()
    strSQL = ("Update Vehicles set Sold = 1  where VehicleID={0}",DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    conn = New SqlConnection(strconn)
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
    conn.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    displayVehicle()
End Sub
```

I know its not parametrised but I'm just trying to get it working for the time being, and then I'll tidy it up.

The error states that a ')' is expected after VehicleID={0}" (and a blue mark on Visual Studio shows it too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a `String.Format` in there:

```
strSQL = String.Format(@"Update Vehicles set Sold = 1  where VehicleID={0}",DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much Chris.

Appreciate the speed, and thanks Shai too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `String.Format` after `strSQL =` and before the `("Update`